# Laravel Swagger PHP Couldn't find constant array

Tags: laravel, swagger-php

- darkaonline/l5-swagger: 8.0.2
- PHP Version: 7.3.13
- zircote/swagger-php: 3.1.0
- OS: Windows

I created a `Contract ref` object.
Now in my `ContractController` I want to list an array of contracts.
How can I do it?
I got this error `Couldn't find constant array` when trying to add `type=array` in `OA\Items`

```php
/**
 * @OA\Info(title="Contract API", version="1")
 */

class ContractController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Post(
     *     path="/api/v1/contract/list",
     *     tags={"contact"},
     *     summary="List Contract",
     *     operationId="list",
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="keyword",
     *         in="path",
     *         description="keyword to search contracts",
     *         required=false,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *             type="string"
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="lang_code",
     *         in="path",
     *         description="lang_code define language client used",
     *         required=false,
     *         @OA\Schema(
     *             type="string",
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="successful",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *              @OA\Items(
     *                  type=array, #This is where I got the error
     *                  ref="#/components/schemas/Contract"
     *              )
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=400,
     *         description="Wrong"
     *     )
     * )
     */
    public function list(Request $request)
    {
        $contracts = Contract::factory()->count(10)->make();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'good',
            'contracts' => $contracts
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * @OA\Schema(
 *     description="Contract model",
 *     type="object",
 *     title="Contract model"
 * )
 */
class Contract extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The unique identifier of a product in our catalog.
     *
     * @var integer
     * @OA\Property(format="int64", example=1)
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @OA\Property(format="string", example="contract 001")
     */
    public $contract_title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="array",` (with `"`s) instead of  `type=array,`

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but
Try to use

```
 *            @OA\MediaType(
 *                 mediaType="application/json",
 *                 @OA\Schema(
 *                 type="array",
 *                      @OA\Items(
 *                          ref="#/components/schemas/Contract"
 *                      ),
 *                 )
 *          )
```

Insead of `@OA\JsonContent`